# Dealing with tree conflicts in an SVN 1.7 feature branch

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, tree-conflict

I created a feature branch because I need to restructure a fairly large project.  The feature branch is 70% moving stuff around and 20% modifying code and 10% new code.  It looks something like this.

```
Trunk     Branch     Actions 
2000   =  2001       create branch
|         2002       move lots of file and directories plus a few file edits
|         2003       lots of edits plus a few more file moves
2004      |          a few edits to files that have been moved in the branch
|         2005       some more edits and a new file or two
2006      |          a few edits to files that have been moved in the branch
|         2007       feature is done... time to pull changes from the trunk
```

When I try to pull the changes from the trunk into the branch I see a "tree conflict" error and not much else.  This is what I found when, I traced a file that was moved in the branch and modified in the trunk.

```
\old\path\file.txt - trunk version 2006
\new-path\file.txt - branch version 2007

---- I would like ----
\new-path\file.txt - merged trunk version 2006 and branch version 2007
```

I'm using SVN 1.7 and the latest TortoiseSVN client so I thought the changes would be tracked auto-magically and this wouldn't happen... I guess I was wrong. My first thought is to use the command line to create another branch then merge the changesets one-by-one until I get everything working again but I'm not really sure which arguments to use to do this.  I feel like commit 2002 completely destroyed my ancestry/history but I'm not sure.

Any advice on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought the changes would be tracked auto-magically and this wouldn't happen...

No, rename + edit on opposite sides of merge will give you tree conflict even in 1.8+ (there merge is slightly improved, contrary to 1.7)

> thought is to use the command line to create another branch then merge the changesets one-by-one

Wrong idea. Because you know both sources of tree-conflicts, you have forcibly merge `\old\path\file.txt` to `\new-path\file.txt` and only after this mergeset, merge trees `\old\path\` and `\new-path\` - without tree conflicts

PS - In order to avoid "Refactoring Hell" in Subversion I always recommend refactor + merge refactored separately (in SCM with merge as first class citizen) and just replace WC by content of working dir of Mercurial after successful merge (you can clone SVN-repos, but can't push mergesets back)

Comment: Basically followed your advice.  Used `svn diff --summarize -r2003:HEAD https://my.repo/my/project/trunk` to get a list of changes, merged them into my branch, then made my branch the new trunk.  Kinda ugly, but it worked.